# Trying to display values from array with foreach and switch statements

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, switch-statement

So I am trying to build the functions I need for some custom post types in wordpress, but before I try to figure out how to dynamically call the variables, I need to make this code work. I think my problem is maybe in the array itself or the Foreach loop. When I run the code, I am expecting a result for a High, medium, and low price point, but It is displaying only the high price point, three times. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

//variables that will be pulled from multiple post types and fields
//p_high, med and low are product multipliers

$client_lvl =array("High","Med", "Low");
$p_high= 2;
$p_med= 1.5;
$p_low =1.1;
$cogs= 10;
$img_count =3;
$img_cost= 10;
$area= 40;
$m_type=  'Flat';

//Loops through array to display high, medium, and low price

Foreach ($client_lvl as $lvl)
{
If ($lvl ='High'){
$multiplier=$p_high;}
elseif($lvl ='Med')
{$multiplier=$p_med;
$m_high=$p_high;}
else {
$multiplier=$p_low;
$m_high=$p_high;}

//calculator that determines price based on multiplier type (m_type)

switch ($m_type) {

     case 'Area':
         if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high * $area; 
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            }

         $price= $multiplier * $area;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";

         break;

     case 'Image':
     if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high * $img_count *$cogs;
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            } 

         $price= $multiplier * $img_count *$cogs;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";
         break;

     case 'Commission':
     if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high + $cogs;
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            } 
         $price= $multiplier + $cogs;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";
         break;

     case 'Flat':
     if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high;
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            } 
         $price= $multiplier;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";
         break;

     case 'Commission+Image':
     if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high + ($img_cost*$img_count);
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            } 
         $price= $multiplier + ($img_cost*$img_count);
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";
         break;

     case'Price':
     if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high * $cogs;
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            } 
         $price= $multiplier * $cogs;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";
         break;
}}

/*End goal is to display the $price variable next to the product depending on if client has the High, medium, or low rate. Rate will be pulled from "client" data, m_type and multipliers will be pulled from "Product group" data, and all other variables will be found in the "product" data. 
If client is not logged in, multiplier uses high value.<br><br>



*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if statements, you have to use the double equal ("==") instead of the simple equal in order to do a comparison.

The simple equal is for variable assignment so $level will be always equal to "high".

Comment: thanks, that looks like it should fix it. I'll play with it this evening.

Answer (score 0):

In `if` condition you should check not assign.try this:

```
<?php

//variables that will be pulled from multiple post types and fields
//p_high, med and low are product multipliers

$client_lvl =array("High","Med", "Low");
$p_high= 2;
$p_med= 1.5;
$p_low =1.1;
$cogs= 10;
$img_count =3;
$img_cost= 10;
$area= 40;
$m_type=  'Flat';

//Loops through array to display high, medium, and low price

Foreach ($client_lvl as $lvl)
{
If ($lvl =='High'){
$multiplier=$p_high;}
elseif($lvl =='Med')
{$multiplier=$p_med;
$m_high=$p_high;}
else {
$multiplier=$p_low;
$m_high=$p_high;}

//calculator that determines price based on multiplier type (m_type)

switch ($m_type) {

     case 'Area':

         if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high * $area; 
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            }

         $price= $multiplier * $area;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";

         break;

     case 'Image':
     if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high * $img_count *$cogs;
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            } 

         $price= $multiplier * $img_count *$cogs;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";
         break;

     case 'Commission':
     if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high + $cogs;
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            } 
         $price= $multiplier + $cogs;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";
         break;

     case 'Flat':
     if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high;
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            } 
         $price= $multiplier;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";
         break;

     case 'Commission+Image':
     if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high + ($img_cost*$img_count);
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            } 
         $price= $multiplier + ($img_cost*$img_count);
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";
         break;

     case'Price':
     if (isset($m_high)){
            $price_high= $m_high * $cogs;
            echo "The High price was \${$price_high}<br/>";
            } 
         $price= $multiplier * $cogs;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";
         break;
}}

/*End goal is to display the $price variable next to the product depending on if client has the High, medium, or low rate. Rate will be pulled from "client" data, m_type and multipliers will be pulled from "Product group" data, and all other variables will be found in the "product" data. 
If client is not logged in, multiplier uses high value.<br><br>



*/
?>
```

hope it helps;

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single equal sign in your if statements. The single equal is an assignment operator. You need to use the comparison operator == here.

So in your code when you want to compare the variable $lvl with the string 'high' you are actually assigning the value 'high' to $lvl. That's why you always get the high value.

Your code should look like this:

```
foreach ($client_lvl as $lvl) {
    If ($lvl == 'High'){
        $multiplier=$p_high;
    } elseif($lvl =='Med'){
        $multiplier=$p_med;
        $m_high=$p_high;
    } else {
        $multiplier=$p_low;
        $m_high=$p_high;
    }
```

Or you can use a switch statement instead.